# codeigniter active records do not return expected result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have three tables as

```
+----------+ +-------------+
| adv      | | removed_adv |
+==========+ +=============+
| id       | | id          |
| group    | | adv_id      |
| category | | member_id   |
| title    | +-------------+
| path     | 
| duration |
+----------+
```

i want to get data from adv table for a given group and category. but the result set should not include ads if removed_adv.advid = adv.id. i have tried following. it returns all the records without `filtering by  $this->db->where_not_in('adv.id', 'ids from removed_adv');`

```
$this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('adv');
            $this->db->where_not_in('adv.id', 'ids from removed_adv');
            $this->db->where_in(array(
                'category' => $cat_id,
                'group' => $group_id
            ));            
            return $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This's my `SELECT` statement: `SELECT * FROM adv WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT adv_id FROM removed_adv) AND group IN (group_id1, group_id2,...) AND category IN (category1, category2,...)`

So you should print your SQL statement using `$this->db->last_query()` and run on SQL query browser/phpMyAdmin, etc.

And here is my PHP code

```
$query = $this->db->select('adv_id')->get('removed_adv');
$adv_id_array = $query->result_array();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('adv');
$this->db->where_not_in('adv.id', $adv_id_array);
$this->db->where_in(array(
    'category' => $cat_id,
    'group' => $group_id
));            
return $this->db->get();
```